# Estimating percentiles in a skewed distribution (doesn't need to be exact)

Tags: excel, statistics, distribution, skew

This may be more of a statistics question, and I'd like to find a solution with Excel.  I'd rather use simple VBA if any coding is necessary.

Is there a way to estimate the percentile of a specific data point in a skewed distribution?  I don't need exact percentiles and only need a reasonable estimate.  I work on analyses that rely on weighted average benchmarks reported by multiple sources.  All of my sources report the 25th, 50th, 75th, and 90th percentiles as well as the mean and standard deviation.  We use these benchmarks to set a target range, and our goal is for our results from a specific analysis to land somewhere within the published percentiles.  I'm often asked to indicate what percentile our specific result is at, and all I can provide is broad ranges like 25th-50th, etc.  So, I'm then asked to use simple extrapolation to determine the specific percentile of the specific result, and I know that using this method is inaccurate.

Mean and median differ in 99% of cases in my data set, but % difference between mean and median on average is only 6%.  Only about 10% of cases have mean and median with greater than 10% difference.

For the 90% of cases with relatively low % difference between mean and median, can I assume the normal distribution?

For cases with higher % difference between mean and median, can I make an assumption that will help me estimate more accurately?  I could for these cases just use the normal distribution and send my percentile estimate along with a note indicating that the estimate is likely off in one direction or another, but I'd rather give a better estimate.

Responding to cybernetic.nomad:

First, thanks for commenting!  Second, it doesn't seem to work.  I think I don't have enough data.  The attached image shows an example.  The first 5 rows show one set of my weighted average benchmarks for a single case.  Below that, I added two lines--one with my "target" amount.  This could be any number but, to test out the formula you suggested, I entered my 50th percentile weighted average.  The row below that has the results of the formula =percentrank.exc(25th:90th,target).  The result should be 0.5 but it's not, so I don't think this works.  [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZVd.png)

Comment: I thnk you are looking for [`PERCENTRANK.INC`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PERCENTRANK-INC-function-149592C9-00C0-49BA-86C1-C1F45B80463A) or [`PERCENTRANK.EXC`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PERCENTRANK-EXC-function-D8AFEE96-B7E2-4A2F-8C01-8FCDEDAA6314)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I copied an example below.  I entered my 25th, 50th, 75th, and 90th pctl weighted averages then set my target equal to the 50th pctl.  When I use percentrank.exc to determine the pctl of my target, the formula gives me 40th pctl.  It should give me the 50th pctl.                                    -----                                                                                                             25th pctl   418,693  
50th pctl 512,177  
75th pctl 609,395  
90th pctl 757,445  
  
Target 512,177  
Percentrank.exc 0.40 <==should be 50th pctl

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58715726/edit) instead of adding information in comment. Adding sample data and expected outcome would also be helppful